# Ajax is not working properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

Here is my ajax code

```
$('.AllTaskDownloadButton').live('click', '.CheckBoxesForDownload', function(){

    var n = $( "input:checked.CheckBoxesForDownload" ).length;
    var arr=[]
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        arr.push($($( "input:checked.CheckBoxesForDownload" )[i]).val())
    }
    alert(arr)
    //passing requestId to servlet
    $.ajax({
        url:"/test/DownloadDeleteTask",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {requestIds:arr,
               operationType:'download' },
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
            dowloadTasks();
        }
    });//ajax

    });
```

and here is my servlet code:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String operationType = request.getParameter("operationType");

if (operationType.equalsIgnoreCase("download")) {

      out.print("download");

  }// if
```

but my `downloadTasks()` is not getting called.

please help to FIX the issue?

Comment: Do you have a spelling mistake? `dowloadTasks`?

Comment: Are you seeing the alert in the success callback?  Also, is it "downloadTask()" or "downloadTasks()"?

Comment: no even that alert is not getting call.:(

Comment: Could you add an "error:" callback and console.log the error message?

Comment: no any error is coming.

Comment: Is the out.print("download") getting logged on the server?

Comment: yes.
request is coming properly.but response doesn't .

Comment: i am using response.setContentType("text/html");

Comment: Last thing I can think to try on your end if you have already tried adding error: callback -- add the complete: callback that fires after success/error callbacks to see if it has any data in it that might help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

stringify the json in the data part of the ajax call and add contentType:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test/DownloadDeleteTask",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({requestIds:arr,
        operationType:"download" 
    }),
    success:function(result){
        alert(result);
        dowloadTasks();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did that actually fix the problem?  You shouldn't need to stringify your data JSON object.

Comment: array is coming null in servlet.

Comment: well, I read in the jQuery documents that you do not have to stringify the data, but it helped me other several times.

Comment: assuming the array (arr) isn't null when you send it, maybe adding contentType helps (updated answer)

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" doesn't solve array null issue.